# passing text_field values in ajx on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using

```
<%= text_field 'person', 'one',:id => 'test', :onchange=>remote_function(:url=>{:action=>"update"}, :update=>"test") %>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Now I just want to send the value of text_field with :action
i.e `:url=>{:action=>"update(value_of_text_field_entered"}`

Don't want to use params[:person][:one].

Any suggestions?or how can I use <%= observe_field %> to send the value with action?

Comment: please check my answer & let me know if this not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one also:

`<%= text_field 'person', 'one' %>`

```
### Paste following code in your javascript

$("#person_one").live("change", function(){
  $.ajax({
    complete:function(request){},
    data:'person_one='+ $(this).val(),
    dataType:'script',
    type:'get',
    url: '/update'route
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<%= text_field 'person', 'one',:id => 'test' %>

<%= observe_field 'persone_one', 
     :url=>{:action=>"update"} ,
 :frequency => 0.25,
     :update=>'test',
     :with => 'person_one'
     %>

<div id="test"></div>
```

you get value of textfiled in **params[:person_one]**

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use a javascript code, "this.value()"