# Populate textfields on new form from another model's existing records on select rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, model, collection-select

I have a `DefaultTemplate` model with existing records in it. I have another `Template` model where i have a collection_select with `DefaultTemplate`'s Records.

What i want to do is that as soon as user selects one of these options, its associated data such as the content and type should be automatically populated in the text_fields of the New Form of Template so they can be saved.

I have researched and found that i can do this with JQuery and Ajax Calls, however i'm clueless about where to start? I referred [Auto populate text_fields based on selected item from another collection_select in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086142/auto-populate-text-fields-based-on-selected-item-from-another-collection-select) and it answers what i want but the person himself finds the code horrible. I'll be grateful for any help. Thanx

Comment: Downvoting for awfully formatted question.

Comment: Whats so awful in this? I tried to keep it direct and simple. Cant get what's  wrong?

Comment: It's 8 lines of continuous text. Can use some line breaks. Please ping me when you reformat it and I will remove the down vote.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, will this do? i 'm new to stack overflow as you would have already guessed, so i don't really know what would be the proper way. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!**

ok, so after scratching my head for 2 days, i found that the answer was rather simple. Only i have been too afraid to even give ajax a try that i never really paid much attention to it. Just in case some one is looking for the same thing, here is the solution that worked for me.

**application.js file**

```
$(function($) {
    $("#email_template_id").change(function() {
        var selected_id = $("#email_template_id").val()
        if (selected_id == '')
        {
          $('#email_template_email_subject').val('')
        }
        else {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/default_email_templates/" + selected_id + ".json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
              $('#email_template_email_subject').val(data.email_subject)
            }
          });
        }
    });
});
```

**View** (In `_form.html.erb` of the EmailTemplate where the DefaultEmailTemplate is the Model whose values should be appearing on selection )

```
<%= form_for(@email_template) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :default_email_template_id, "Template Type" %>
     <%= f.collection_select(:id, DefaultEmailTemplate.all, :id, :email_type, {prompt: "Select one"}, {:data => {remote: true}}) %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :email_subject %>
     <%= f.text_field :email_subject %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

We can reduce the ajax code by simply passing parameters one after the other but, i'm not well aware of that and dint really try that yet. Please post any suggestions about the code. Thanx.

P.S: Maybe i wasn't looking properly but when i did, these helped me a lot

[How to do an Ajax GET request to get data from rails and pass it to javascript(google maps)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589508/how-to-do-an-ajax-get-request-to-get-data-from-rails-and-pass-it-to-javascriptg)

[passing text_field values in ajx on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720867/passing-text-field-values-in-ajx-on-rails)

Answer (score -1):

```js
public JsonResult FillTask(int projectID)
        {
            List<tbltask> task = new List<tbltask>();
            task = te.getTasks(projectID);
            model.Tasks = task;
            model.task = task.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.TaskId.ToString(),
                Text = x.TaskName
            }).ToList();
            //var tasks = model.Tasks.Where(c => c.ProjectId == project);
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblprojects").change(function()
        {
            var projectID = $('#tblprojects').val();   
            if(projectID>0){
                FillTask(projectID)
            }
        });
    });
    function FillTask(projectID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("FillTask", "TimeEntry")',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { 'projectID': projectID},
            success: function (data) {  
                $(data.task).each(function()
                {
                    //this refers to the current item being iterated over
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', this.Value).text(this.Text);

                    $('#task').append(option);
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

i have bind task which are related to that project only when i click on project task detail of that project load into another drop-down its called cascading dropdown using ajax and jquery !! jason method also

Comment: Cascading Select looks good. I'll give it a try and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Thanx of this even though i dint really apply it. But this was really helpful cause i came to know something that would be helpful for me in the coming stages in my work. Will get back to you for this.

Comment: Welcome @Aakansha you can Ask anytime if any help needed .